# Update table values based on which button clicked

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a `DetailView` that show all the transaction information from transaction id, name, created_date,...., and status. In this pages I have 3 button they are cancel, approve, and reject.

what I want to do is when I clicked button cancel the status changed to "Cancelled", some goes for reject and approve that change the status to "Rejected" and "Success".

how can I do this?

I've tried to add form in the template with hidden input and method post, but after submit it show 405 error page.

html

```
{% if transaction.status == "Approval" or transaction.status == "Rejected" or transaction.status == "Failed"  %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="Cancelled">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--danger">
        <i class="btn__icon">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2"
                stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                class="feather feather-x">
                <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line>
                <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line>
            </svg>
        </i>
        <span>Cancel</span>
    </button>
</form>
{%endif%}
```

View

```
class DetailTransaction(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DetailView):
    model = Transaction
    field = ['status']
    template_name = 'transaction/transaction-detail.html'
    form_class = TransactionCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("transaction-view")
    success_message = "Transaction updated successfully."

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def form_valid(self, form):

    status = form.cleaned_data["status"]
    transaction = Transaction(
    status = status
    )
    transaction.save()

    return super(DetailTransaction, self).form_valid(form)
```

model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
        Status = (
        ('Approval', 'Approval'),
        ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),
        ('Success', 'Success'),
        ('Failed', 'Failed'),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Status, default='Approval')
```

Comment: Add you code please (the view, the template, and relevant code from your model). Otherwise it is difficult to know what exactly went wrong. In general, your way of solution sounds right.

Comment: @Risadinha , I've added my code, I tried this solution a few days ago here's  I tried to recreate it to post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing because you have not posted any code.

405 indicates that your view does not accept POST requests.

There are different ways to solve this in Django.

#### Decorator

Use the `require_http_methods` decorator as explained in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods.

#### UpdateView

If you like class based generic views, use an https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView.

You can use UpdateViews even if you only want to change a single field of your model.

Comment: I tried using UpdateView it give me this error  __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'